# Deleting Node and NPM to fix issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

So i've been having an issue with npm not working. I've been trying to install gulp and it goes in but once I try to use it, it just fails and give [image: this error]

I've tried everything I can think of and had multiple people try to help me out but nothing works. Would deleting all files including npm and nodejs and uninstalling node help my issue if i start fresh?

code I am trying to run 
`var gulp = require('gulp'); gulp.task('myTask', function(){ return console.log('hello gulp'); });`

Comment: Lol, nice of you to add single quotes in your path, I am sure that has nothing to with it... or not... Also, how come your path starts with `C:\c\...` seems like it doubled the drive there (maybe bash command in the back?)

Comment: I'm new to all of this and how would i fix this if this is the issue?

Comment: If that would be the case, you could move it to a folder on `C:\` itself, but it would rather be helpful if you show the `myTask` maybe the problem is  there instead. Also, could you give an idea which terminal we are seeing? Is this git bash?

Comment: Yes it is git bash. myTask looks like 

var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('myTask', function(){
  return console.log('hello gulp');
});

I dont really know how to move these super complex files . I already messed up once and spent some time fixing everything. Now this is the issue, but before it was still giving me the same issue and I dont know what else to do. I can get to the files through the terminal, but when I try to find it in the actual computer files, i cant find the AppData directory

Comment: Can you add it to the question using the [edit] link? You might as well add your gulp config ;)

Comment: my gulp config? like what it says on the file? I'll see if i can find that

Comment: I added the code to the question as well